# How to turn headless on after launch?

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I'd like to load the page with headless off to let me login.

After login I want to hide it, turning on the headless and let it do what it has to do.

How can I turn on/off the headless after launch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot toggle headless on fly. But you can share the login using [cookies](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagecookiesurls) and [setCookie](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagesetcookiecookies) if you want.

We will create a simple class to keep the code clean (or that's what I believe for these type of work since they usually get big later). You can do this without all these complexity though. Also, Make sure the cookies are serialized. Do not pass array to toe setCookie function.

There will be three main functions.

## 1. `init()`

To create a page object. Mostly to make sure the headless and headful version has similar style of browsing, same user agent etc. Note, I did not include the code to set user agents, it's just there to show the concept.

```
async init(headless) {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless
    });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    // do more page stuff before loading, ie: user agent and so on
    return {
        page,
        browser
    };
}
```

## 2. `getLoginCookies()`

Example of showing how you can get cookies from the browser.

```
// will take care of our login using headful
async getLoginCookies() {
    const {
        page,
        browser
    } = await this.init(false)

    // asume we load page and login here using some method
    // and the website sets some cookie
    await page.goto('http://httpbin.org/cookies/set/authenticated/true')

    // store the cookie somewhere
    this.cookies = await page.cookies() // the cookies are collected as array

    // close the page and browser, we are done with this
    await page.close();
    await browser.close();
    return true;
}
```

You won't need such function if you can provide cookies manually. You can use EditThisCookie or any cookie editing tool. You will get an **array of all cookies** for that site. Here is how you can do this,

[image]

## 3. `useHeadless()`

Example of showing how you can set cookies to a browser.

```
// continue with our normal headless stuff
async useHeadless() {
    const {
        page,
        browser
    } = await this.init(true)

    // we set all cookies we got previously
    await page.setCookie(...this.cookies) // three dots represents spread syntax. The cookies are contained in a array.

    // verify the cookies are working properly
    await page.goto('http://httpbin.org/cookies');
    const content = await page.$eval('body', e => e.innerText)
    console.log(content)

    // do other stuff
    // close the page and browser, we are done with this
    // deduplicate this however you like
    await page.close();
    await browser.close();
    return true;
}
```

## 4. Creating our own awesome puppeteer instance

```
// let's use this

(async () => {
    const loginTester = new myAwesomePuppeteer()
    await loginTester.getLoginCookies()
    await loginTester.useHeadless()
})()
```

## Full Code

Walk through the code to understand it better. It's all commented.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

class myAwesomePuppeteer {
    constructor() {
        // keeps the cookies on the class scope
        this.cookies;
    }

    // creates a browser instance and applies all kind of setup
    async init(headless) {
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
            headless
        });
        const page = await browser.newPage();
        // do more page stuff before loading, ie: user agent and so on
        return {
            page,
            browser
        };
    }

    // will take care of our login using headful
    async getLoginCookies() {
        const {
            page,
            browser
        } = await this.init(false)

        // asume we load page and login here using some method
        // and the website sets some cookie
        await page.goto('http://httpbin.org/cookies/set/authenticated/true')

        // store the cookie somewhere
        this.cookies = await page.cookies()

        // close the page and browser, we are done with this
        await page.close();
        await browser.close();
        return true;
    }

    // continue with our normal headless stuff
    async useHeadless() {
        const {
            page,
            browser
        } = await this.init(true)

        // we set all cookies we got previously
        await page.setCookie(...this.cookies)

        // verify the cookies are working properly
        await page.goto('http://httpbin.org/cookies');
        const content = await page.$eval('body', e => e.innerText)
        console.log(content)

        // do other stuff
        // close the page and browser, we are done with this
        // deduplicate this however you like
        await page.close();
        await browser.close();
        return true;
    }
}

// let's use this
(async () => {
    const loginTester = new myAwesomePuppeteer()
    await loginTester.getLoginCookies()
    await loginTester.useHeadless()
})()
```

Here is the result,

```
➜  node app.js
{
  "cookies": {
    "authenticated": "true"
  }
}
```

So in short,

- You can use the `cookies` function to get cookies.
- You can use extensions like [Edit This Cookie](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/editthiscookie/fngmhnnpilhplaeedifhccceomclgfbg) to get cookies from your normal browser.
- You can use `setCookie` to set any kind of cookie you get from browser.