# Can the browser turned headless mid-execution when it was started normally, or vice-versa?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer

I want to start a chromium browser instant headless, do some automated operations, and then turn it visible before doing the rest of the stuff.

Is this possible to do using Puppeteer, and if it is, can you tell me how? And if it is not, is there any other framework or library for browser automation that can do this?

So far I've tried the following but it didn't work.

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({'headless': false});
browser.headless = true;
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto('https://news.ycombinator.com', {waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});
await page.pdf({path: 'hn.pdf', format: 'A4'});
```

Comment: You can't, headless is a command argument added when you lunch Chromium.

Comment: Worth checking out is [a useful answer from another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54300837/6243352) that offers code to do this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Short answer: It's not possible

Chrome only allows to either start the browser in *headless* or *non-headless* mode. You have to specify it when you launch the browser and it is not possible to switch during runtime.

What is possible, is to launch a second browser and reuse cookies (and any other data) from the first browser.

#### Long answer

You would assume that you could just reuse the data directory when calling [`puppeteer.launch`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#puppeteerlaunchoptions), but this is currently not possible due to multiple bugs ([#1268](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/1268), [#1270](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/1270) in the puppeteer repo).

So the best approach is to [save any cookies](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/1316#issuecomment-468581416) or local storage data that you need to share between the browser instances and restore the data when you launch the browser. You then visit the website a second time. Be aware that any state the website has in terms of JavaScript variable, will be lost when you recrawl the page.

#### Process

Summing up, the whole process should look like this (or vice versa for headless to headfull):

- Crawl in non-headless mode until you want to switch mode
- [Serialize cookies](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/1316#issuecomment-468581416)
- Launch or reuse second browser (in headless mode)
- Restore cookies
- Revisit page
- Continue crawling

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, this isn't currently possible since the headless switch occurs via Chromium launch flags.

I usually do this with `userDataDir`, which [the Chromium docs describe](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/refs/heads/main/docs/user_data_dir.md#introduction) as follows:

> The user data directory contains profile data such as history, bookmarks, and cookies, as well as other per-installation local state.

Here's a simple example. This launches a browser headlessly, sets a local storage value on an arbitrary page, closes the browser, re-opens it headfully, retrieves the local storage value and prints it.

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer"); // ^18.0.4

const url = "https://www.example.com";
const opts = {userDataDir: "./data"};

let browser;
(async () => {
  {
    browser = await puppeteer.launch({...opts, headless: true});
    const [page] = await browser.pages();
    await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: "domcontentloaded"});
    await page.evaluate(() => localStorage.setItem("hello", "world"));
    await browser.close();
  }
  {
    browser = await puppeteer.launch({...opts, headless: false});
    const [page] = await browser.pages();
    await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: "domcontentloaded"});
    const result = await page.evaluate(() => localStorage.getItem("hello"));
    console.log(result); // => world
  }
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close())
;
```

Change `const opts = {userDataDir: "./data"};` to `const opts = {};` and you'll see `null` print instead of `world`; the user data doesn't persist.

The [answer from a few years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55815087/6243352) mentions issues with `userDataDir` and suggests a cookies solution. That's fine, but I haven't had any issues with `userDataDir` so either they've been resolved on the Puppeteer end or my use cases haven't triggered the issues.

There's a useful-looking answer from a reputable source in [How to turn headless on after launch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54292780/how-to-turn-headless-on-after-launch/54300837#54300837) but I haven't had a chance to try it yet.