# Puppeteer, how to close the browser and save session? After user interaction on login page?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I'm trying to create a selenium headless=false which allow user to login gmail. After they login, i want to make it headless=true and close the window, but save the session.

My Current code: i dont how to make it detects if the user has sucessfully login and how do i make it close the browser?

```
(async () => {
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false
});
const page = await browser.newPage();

await page.goto('https://accounts.google.com/');
);
```

Comment: Does this (save cookies and restore them) help you? https://stackoverflow.com/a/55815087/5627599

Comment: @ThomasDondorf even if i save the cookies, is it possible to open the browser (headless false) and continue the session?

Comment: If the session is only bound to the cookie: Yes. You can save the cookie and restore it to continue the session.

Comment: @man Selenium? Do you mean Puppeteer?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can the browser turned headless mid-execution when it was started normally, or vice-versa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55809241/can-the-browser-turned-headless-mid-execution-when-it-was-started-normally-or-v)