# Securing credential inside DOM of puppeteer, Headless Chrome

Tags: selenium, puppeteer, google-chrome-headless, headless-browser, webautomation

I'm designing a service that provides,

1. Hidden automated login of existing site with a credential provided by external source
2. Hand over a logon browser to a user by enabling it visible

So, this service provides logon browser instantly when a user wants. I'm thinking to using puppeteer, and my question is

- In #1, could puppeteer have enough security to protect the credential(ID/PW) during inputting them via puppeteer API? (Don't worry about encryption between external source and application. Only between application and puppeteer if a hacker could monitor DOM structure of hidden puppeteer session or not.)
- In #2, can I dynamically set hidden browser visible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Communication between Node.js and the browser**

The communication between the Node.js environment and the browser is not encrypted by default as it is using the unencrypted Websocket protocol (`ws://`) instead of the encrypted one (`wss://`). If your puppeteer instance connects from one machine to another, this means people might be able to sniff on the connection ([more information](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55815087/5627599)).

Keep in mind, that if your Node.js application and your browser are running on the same machine, this doesn't really matter. Of course, any attacker that has access to your computer and the running application can also monitor memory or even directly connect to your running browser via a WebSocket.

**Dynamically show or hide the browser**

Regarding your second part: It is not possible to change the browser state from "visible" to invisible (or vice versa) with the puppeteer API. But you can either use the API of your operating system to do that or serialize the state of the browser and transfer the state into another browser instance ([more information](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55815087/5627599)).

Comment: Thanks. I got a great insight from your 2nd answer. Regarding 1st one, I'd go down the path of using C++ library with headless chrome or equivalent to protect internal trace from attacker. I may perform #1 with headless browser or even more native HTTP way then serialize cookies you mentioned in your link to hand it over to a user with visible web browser. It'd be great if there is such seamless solution out there.